# Mocha/Chai - Conditionally invoke desired it block uder describe block

Tags: conditional-statements, mocha.js, chai, describe

Suppose I have before hook at the beginning of describe block, where GET API is called to return array of some objects if data is present in database, otherwise it returns empty array.

First it block under describe is ok, it will check response status and should pass if status is equal to 200. (no matter if response array is empty or array of objects)

But second it block should check the structure of single object in array. So, if array is not empty, everything is ok, but if there is no data and API returns empty array, it will fail. How can I invoke it conditionally, only if response.array is not empty?

Comment: In general, you should test against a known and pre-configured state, so ideally, you should intercept the API call and return a pre-determined response.

Comment: make it a unit test, mock your API to get desired result